# Crystal Reports - One report that lets user select from multiple reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to "merge" 3 big reports.

Is it possible to just create a drop down menu that lets the user select which report to view?

Then just put all 3 reports into one as sub-reports?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- create a dummy main report
- embed each of the 3 reports as a sub-report
- create a pick-list parameter that allows a person to select one of the reports to be shown
- suppress sub-reports that aren't in the parameter's chosen value

** edit **

In addition, create the necessary parameter fields in the main report, then link them to the corresponding parameter fields in each sub-report.  This will eliminate the report from prompting repeated for each parameter.

Comment: thank you so much.  that sounds like what I need.  I had not heard of a "pick list".

Comment: "Pick-list" parameter is basically a list of options available for selection to the user (in your case names of 3 reports). The user can choose the report he wants from the dropdown list.

Comment: This concept does not work if the subreport has parameter. All the sub report parameters shows up when you run the main report.